# Calling static methods on object instances and a side note Java

Tags: java

I was looking of some of the questions, and it lead me to this issue. When you call a static method on a object instances, does it resolve dynamically or statically for example:

```
class A
{
     public static foo() {}
}
class B extends A
{
     public static foo() {}
}
[...]
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     A a = new B();
     a.foo(); // does this all A foo or B foo?
}
```

why I'm asking this is because it would explain why static methods can't be abstract.  Because if A was an interface this would not work if foo was abstract and static.

How does this work internally? Basically how does is know that foo is static to begin with if it doesn't do anything dynamic? Doesn't it still have to inspect the class? Also if it know a is really a B why doesn't it call foo on B?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It resolves it statically based on the *compile-time* type of `a`. The value is ignored, and can even be null:

```
A a = null;
a.foo(); // Still calls A.foo
```

IIRC, at one point it *did* perform a nullity check, but it doesn't now.

I would **strongly** urge you not to do this, and at least some IDEs (including Eclipse) can warn you about this. The code doesn't do what it looks like, and sometimes it can be *very* misleading:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() { /* ... */ });
t.start();
t.sleep(1000);
```

That *looks* like it makes the newly created thread sleep - but actually it's the *current* thread which will sleep. Eek!

IMO, this was effectively a mistake in the design of Java.

Comment: seems like noone can match your speed :)